# Selecting the newest file using ANT

Tags: ant, build, scripting

How would I go about using ANT to select the last file in a directory? 
I have a separate script that's saving a file into a directory at the same time every day with a (DD-MM-YYYY) format.

And I'd like to select the newest file automatically (either by name or the date that it was last modified. 
I have a file structure similar to this.

```
Data
├── 20-08-2017.txt 
├── 21-08-2017.txt 
├── 22-08-2017.txt
```

I'm currently using this to select (and copy) a file manually:

```
<project name="CopyDemo" default="CopyDemo">
    <target name="CopyDemo">
        <copy file="22-08-2017.txt" tofile="file-COPY.txt"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `last` in conjunction with `sort` by date as shown below:

```
<project default="test" name="test">
  <property name="source.directory" value="C:/Users/apps/Data" />
  <target name="test">
    <copy tofile="file-COPY.txt">
      <last id="lastFile">
        <sort>
          <date/>
          <fileset dir="${source.directory}"/>
        </sort>
      </last>
    </copy>
    <echo message="copied file :${ant.refid:lastFile}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```